# I am looking for a latching relay motor start and stop circuit

Tags: relay

I have some past electronics education but have not used in over 30 years.  I am trying to make  a circuit which uses two normally open tact switches and a DPDT single coil latching relay.

I have a circuit that one button is forward and the second reverses the motor.  When I wired it up it would start in one direction and stop with the press of the second switch,  which actually works great for my need.  The problem is I cannot find the mistake I made when wiring it that allowed it to stop instead of reversing.

I actually want to replicate the mistake (I have tried to trace the circuit and cannot find the problem, but it works just right for my device), or find a similar circuit that will allow me to push one button,  the motor starts and continues until the second switch is pressed and then stops. Any suggestions would be helpful as my knowledge is very rusty and I thought the circuit I had would work.

I am on a tight constraint as a client has decided on an electrical or electronic configuration for a project that originally was supposed to be manual. Greatly appreciate any help.

[image: this is the schematic I am using]

Comment: I take it the device in your picture is supposed to be some sort of relay?

Comment: Without a part number and a link to the relay datasheet your relay pin numbering is meaningless. There is a schematic tool on the editor toolbar. It has relays, push-buttons, batteries, etc. Use the LAMP symbol for your motor and an editable schematic will be saved in-line with your post. If you add a schematic in it will force you to think your wiring and logic through.

Comment: https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Catalog%20Drawings/Relays/TX-PCBd-bottom1COIL.jpg

Comment: digikey part number 255-2299-5-ND

Comment: Yes,  I originally wanted a start/reverse circuit,  but when I wired it one switch starts the motor, the other stops it.  Realizing I wired it wrong but also that the outcome was better for my needs

Comment: Basically the motor is connected to a screw drive,  the screw turns counter clockwise pushing a shaft forward, when the shaft is all the way forward it turns,  then the person pushes a button at the desired number of turns, and a cam on the shaft hits a second switch wired in series stopping the motor at the right position.

Comment: So in a nutshell,  three pushbutton tact switches normally open.  one starts the motor,  the other two are series wired to stop the motor,  one pushed by hand when the desired turns are reached, the other a limit switch to stop the motor at a preset location.

Comment: Actually, I figured it out. I removed the wire from pin 4 to the motor, then ran it right to the negative battery connection.  This way it starts with one button, then stops with the other. I just have to reverse the polarity at the motor to get the direction I need.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the DPDT relay as a reversing switch. Wire the contacts to the motor and the power source. If you add a SPST toggle switch, that would be the main power ON-OFF switch.
Now you just have to control the relay. Relay ON for one direction, and relay OFF for the other direction. A second SPST switch could be the forward/reverse switch.
Or instead of 2 switches you can use a single center-OFF, DPDT toggle switch. One set of switch contacts turn on the motor circuit, while the other set of contacts determine if the relay is ON or OFF. Do you need a schematic for one option or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Update....

Here is another circuit using 555 timer.
Depending on your wireing of your dc motor, if one of the push button is pressed just once it activates the relay and the motor will go forward, also if the other is pressed the motor will reverse.
Note: if you pressed a button it is activated to deactivate it, you need to press the button again
[image: timer control motor]

You can also add a led to the circuit close to the button in order to know the one that is active. Check the one below:
[image: timer motor control 2]

Bro why not use h-bridge instead of relay?
Here is the circuit below

[image: H-bridge driver]

Comment: "*... that will allow me to push one button, the motor starts and continues until the second switch is pressed and then stops.*" Your circuit doesn't meet the requirements. Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: I don’t know what this is. This site had my name wrong and someone else’s picture. I have no idea what this is. Apparently it was four years ago using my old email

Comment: @Shawna maybe you gave your email login details to someone